# WebSockets in Safari: incorrect disconnection

Tags: node.js, safari, websocket

Safari don't close connection like Firefox, Chrome or IE. I've tested on OS X and iOS with Node.js. The connection is closed after a variable time. In OS X even if I terminated Safari application.

Comment: Can you provide more details?  How about some logs of how you see the disconnection?

Comment: Code 1006 CLOSE_ABNORMAL - was closed after 1.4 minutes after I closed Safari.